# Parse XML string in real-time using Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to implement real-time parsing of XML strings from an eye-tracker using TCP server-client API, for:
1)Store them in a .csv or other format for offline analysis.
2)Display gaze coordinates on the screen.

One small sample of xml string looks like this:

```
    <REC FPOGX="0.68449" FPOGY="0.81953" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.77747" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />
    <REC FPOGX="0.68449" FPOGY="0.81953" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.77747" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />
    <REC FPOGX="0.68449" FPOGY="0.81953" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.77747" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />
    <REC FPOGX="0.68405" FPOGY="0.81942" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.80640" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />
    <REC FPOGX="0.68405" FPOGY="0.81942" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.80640" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />
    <REC FPOGX="0.68405" FPOGY="0.81942" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.80640" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />
```

The eye-tracker sends one sample (like the one above) every 6.6 milliseconds. Most of the things I've looked at, take static xml files and do the parsing. However, in my case, I want to do that in real-time so that I can read the X,Y gaze coordinates (e.g. FPOGX and FPOGY) and display them on the screen (for that I will use an experiment design software). Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have the code for receiving and reading the xml?

Comment: In which format do you receive the xml string? Or you're saying that you already have a string with that content that you posted?

Comment: @JakubSzlaur I already have a string with that content. Actually, I get one such line every 6.6 milliseconds and I want to read it in real-time, extract the variables of interest, maybe store them on a .csv and then access the last coordinates and display them on the screen.

Comment: @TenaciousB the code for reading no because I cannot find anything to parse xml in real time. Since the communication between the computer and the eye-tracker is socket based, I use sth like this (s=socket):                                                            gaze_data= s.recv(1024)                                                      
print(bytes.decode(gaze_data))

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving it as a string of xml, you can simply do `ET.fromstring(<xml_string>).attrib` for your data structure:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

def parse_xml(xml_string):
    tree = ET.fromstring(xml_string) # et.parse if you are receiving a file
    return tree.attrib

my_xml = '<REC FPOGX="0.68295" FPOGY="0.82154" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.83740" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />'

data = parse_xml(my_xml)

print(data)
```

Output:

```py
{'FPOGX': '0.68295', 'FPOGY': '0.82154', 'FPOGS': '1789.73828', 'FPOGD': '0.83740', 'FPOGID': '4894', 'FPOGV': '1', 'CX': '0.95781', 'CY': '0.39074', 'CS': '0'}
```

For the csv part, you can use this `append_csv_dict` funciton (standard function I use):

```py
def append_csv_dict(path, data):
    '''
    Append a csv with a dictionary keys as column headers
    Args:
        path (str): Path to the csv file
        data (dict or list): Dictionary or list(dict) with keys as 
                             column  headers and values as column data
    '''
    with open(path, 'a') as file:
        # set the field names to the keys of the dictionary or keys of the first item
        fieldnames = list(data.keys()) if isinstance(data, dict) else data[0].keys()
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        # write the header if the file is new
        if file.tell() == 0:
            writer.writeheader()
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            # write the row
            writer.writerow(data)
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            # write the rows if it is a list
            writer.writerows(data)
            
# append 10 times to show how it works
for i in range(10):
    append_csv_dict('./data.csv', data)
```

Output (data.csv):

```py
FPOGX,FPOGY,FPOGS,FPOGD,FPOGID,FPOGV,CX,CY,CS
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
0.68295,0.82154,1789.73828,0.83740,4894,1,0.95781,0.39074,0
```

Comment: Looks good. But I am not sure it works for real-time parsing. I cannot explicitly specify my_xml variable since the eyetracker is working and I have incoming xml string to parse. Fro example, if the eyetracker works for 2 seconds, I have 300 such xml strings to parse and I need to do that synchronously. The .csv part looks very promising.

Comment: modify the above code and put it in your loop, it should work if you are getting a string of xml and loading it into a variable, then use `parse_xml()` on it and append your csv with the results

Answer (score 0):

**This code below should do the trick:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = '<REC FPOGX="0.68295" FPOGY="0.82154" FPOGS="1789.73828" FPOGD="0.83740" FPOGID="4894" FPOGV="1" CX="0.95781" CY="0.39074" CS="0" />'

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
my_dictionary = root.attrib

print("X:{}, Y:{}".format(my_dictionary["FPOGX"], my_dictionary["FPOGY"]))
```

You can work with the string using xml.etree.ElementTree module. The output will be dictionary.

Comment: If the answer helped you please leave a thumbs up :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer but I don't see how this solves the problem of real-time parsing. Consider that the eye-tracker sends one such XML every 6.6 milliseconds. If I get data for 2 seconds, this means about 300 lines of such xml string. So I cannot define the variable xml_string since its content is always changing, as new xml strings are coming in.

Comment: It will work. You don't need to make bariable `xml_string`, just use the `root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)` and `my_dictionary = root.attrib` on the incoming data. ***Also: post your code please***.